# Notification with requireInteraction - how to check if displayed?

Tags: javascript

I show a 'sticky' notification like this:

```
function show(text) {
  let alreadyOn = false; // ??? how to get this ???
  
  if (!alreadyOn) {
    new Notification(text, {
        requireInteraction : true
    });
  }
}

Notification.requestPermission();
show("first");
setTimeout(() => show("second"), 1000);
```

(note this just a sample and you need to permit notification the first time it runs and try again)

Is there a way for my code to later determine if this notification is still on or the user already dismissed it ? That is how to determine `alreadyOn` above ?

Comment: You've not given us enough to go on. You should add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @Andy edited, is that clearer ?

Comment: Is `Notification` a class you've coded, or part of a library? How is it added to the DOM?

Comment: @Andy see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event handler with  `Notification.onclose` method to do something when the `Notification` is closed by the user.

```
Notification.onclose = function () {
  // do something...
}
```